# SAS do loop substring index with if statment

Tags: sas

I have a binary string like '100111111100001111111111000'
It shows as a char variable in SAS. 
How can I capture every single change either from 1 to 0 or 0 to 1?
My idea output would be like

> Blockquote

```
                       type  position
                        1-0      2
                        0-1      4
                        1-0      11
                        0-1      15
                        1-0      22
```

I stuck at how to write a recursive statement.(process like 20000 string all in once , every string could be really long......) I'm thinking I can have

> zero=index(string,'0');  one=index(string,'1');   if zero>one then
>   string=substr(string, zero);  else if zero

Is this a right direction? How should I put in a DO LOOP statement?

Thank you very much

Aaron

Answer (score 4):

Seems reasonable to me. Slightly simplified.

```
do position = 1 to length(String)-1;
  if subpad(string,position,2)='10' then do;
    ... output a row for the 1-0 change ...
  end;
  else if subpad(string,position,2)='01' then do;
    ... output a row for the 0-1 change ...
  end;
end;
```

With you doing whatever it is you want to output (I assume something like setting a variable to '1-0' and then `output;`).

I use SUBPAD there sort of out of habit, SUBSTR should work just as well as long as you check the string length properly.  SUBPAD won't error if it goes past the end of the string is all.

Comment: Where has `subpad()` been all my life?  I have so much code checking fpr string length's, empty strings, etc... and all I ever needed was `subpad()`... Thanks for the tip Joe!

Comment: Maybe my 2016 e-poster will be "When SUBSTR just won't do"... SUBPAD and SUBSTRN are both quite handy functions.

Comment: Wow, so with subpad I will not get these "NOTE: Invalid third argument to function SUBSTR at line 2413 column 3." when second+third argument of substr is longer than the string? Thanks for this tip!

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try these codes to see if this is what you are looking for

data have (keep=type pos);
retain type pos;
x = '100111111100001111111111000';
ct01 = count(x,'01');
ct10 = count(x,'10');

pos = 1;
do i =1 to ct01;
  pos = find(x,'01',pos)+1;
  type='0-1';
  output;
end;

pos = 1;
do i =1 to ct10;
  pos = find(x,'10',pos)+1;
  type='1-0';
  output;
end;

run;

proc sort data=have;
by pos;
run;
```